# CSS background for div element is not working

Tags: html, css, w3.css

I've divided my web page to left and right container(it's working fine). I made new class in div called "user-cover-container" and it only needs to put cover image on the top left side of the page.

Image is in the same folder as css and HTML file. HTML and css files are merged correctly.

```css
.user-cover-container{
      height: 200px;
      width: 100px;
      background-image: url("bck.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
<div class=”user-cover-container”> </div>
```

Comment: The quotes you are using in `<div class=”user-cover-container”> </div>` are wrong. Make it either single or double quotes or without any

Comment: you copy pasted some code from somewhere, and you re not using the normal quotes. check https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/double-quotes-quotation-mark-speech-marks-ascii-code-34.html (34 and 39)

Answer (score 2):

Please check the inverted commas for class attribute in HTML. Change them to - " "

```css
.user-cover-container{
      height: 200px;
      width: 100px;
      background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTlhiyjToS4vgqPDf_ip_MdI8B7RKbfOlCCLsb9qH8d1PPN-rj5TA");
      background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
<div class="user-cover-container"> </div>
```

Comment: Omg what a stupid mistake I made. Thank you, SOLVED!

Answer (score 0):

you have missed the "". add this to your code.

```
<div class="user-cover-container">test </div>
```

```css
.user-cover-container{
      height: 200px;
      width: 100px;
      background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="user-cover-container">test </div>
```